# instance variables initialized inside method

Tags: java

I would like to know the difference or impact at any level if we try to initialize a reference declared at class level inside a method. why would we make a reference at class level and initialize it in method scope.

second ques: what about useBox2

please help with technical justification

```
public class S {

    private MyBox b;

    public void useBox()
    {

        b = getBox()

        b.abc();

     }

    public synchronized void useBox2(){

        b = newBox();
    }

    private Box getBox()
    {

        return new MyBox()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you're referring to is `lazy initialization`, and consists of initializing the object only when needed, to (for example) better manage memory allocation.

Using the `syncronized` keyword will affect how different threads access the method. Being it a class property, its "value" is going to be shared across all threads.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the design in this question.

1. It is better to initialize object variables during the actual object initialization. Otherwise, the code should handle all possible `NullPointerException` cases. I really do not like to put null checks to every possible code line.
2. It is also not a good practice to lazily initialize a object when it is needed with this style. It gets code more messy. There is a need for null check and if object is null and call a method to initialize the object. These routine should be put to every possible code lines which need the object.

I think the above conditions make the code tightly coupled and it will lead more problems. I am questioning why this object is a class variable if it is not needed when initializing the actual object.

**See also**

[Coupling (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))

[Creational design patterns](http://www.javatpoint.com/creational-design-patterns)